# Value 91 at 0 of type java.lang.Byte cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm getting the following error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value 91 at 0 of type java.lang.Byte cannot be converted to JSONObject

And it's because of this line of code:

```
JSONObject jObj = j.getJSONObject(i);
```

I'm doing a `GET` request and I logged it in Android Studio which looks like this:

```
jsonarray [91,109,111,100,101,108,46,83,116,111,114,101,64,52,57,57,54,102,97,56,44,32,109,111,100,101,108
```

In the browser it looks like this:

Link to a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptXzo.png

I had used a `JSONObject`, because I want to do later something like this:

```
String storeName = jObj.getString("STORE NAME");
String street = jObj.getString("STREET");
String city = jObj.getString("CITY");
```

Here is the code:

```
public void getSubprises() {
    Call<List<Store>> call = subpriseAPI.listStores();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Store>>() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Store>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            try {
                JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response.body().toString().getBytes());
                System.out.println("jsonarray "+ j);
                for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jObj = j.getJSONObject(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the numerical JSON value 91 in your `JSONArray` can be converted to a `JSONObject`?

Comment: you can't get street of 91. Dont you need to put jsonobjects inside the jsonarray? Also you are putting bytes inside jsonarray constructor. Put the string that you want it to be a jsonarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```
 JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response.body().toString().getBytes());
```

to

```
 JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response.body().toString());
```

i think this is what you want to do.
If this didn't work, then you really don't know what the response body has inside, to learn use System.out.print function to see what response.body().toString() prints.

if it is something like

[
 {"STORE_NAME" : "abc", "STREET" : "def"}, {"STORE_NAME" : "asw", "STREET" : "rew" }
]

everything is well. Else you need to change the way you get the jsonobject.

EDIT:

["model.Store@4996fa8","model.Store@949eac1","model.Store@c45f266", ...

this output that you wrote in the comments made me realize that you don't need a JSONArray or anything, Response> response already has the Store objects.

And looking that output, response.body() returns List,

then you can do this to get the outputs

EDIT 2:

```
    java.util.Iterator it=response.body().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
         System.out.println(((Store)it.next()).getStreet());
```

Above code will only work if the Store object has the method getStreet of course if not you can use st.street or st. then ctrl+space and find the street like label there.

Comment: I'm using this `String body = new String( response.body().toString().getBytes());` and the output shows me: `body [model.Store@4996fa8, model.Store@949eac1, model.Store@c45f266, model.Store@a8779a7, model.Store@e9de54, model.Store@e4971fd, `  So I'm close, but I still don't know how to fix it..

Comment: Your thing also gave me this as output: `["model.Store@4996fa8","model.Store@949eac1","model.Store@c45f266",`

Comment: Here it is:  `JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response.body().toString());`

Comment: Man you are really misleading us. :) I want to help tough :) Response<List<Store>> response, as you can see response holds a List of store objects. You don't need a JSONArray. This response is a custom class that you wrote? You need to get the List<Store> objects inside the response, you don't need a jsonarray.

Comment: The last edit to my answer will definetly solve your problem. Check the updated answer ( Can you delete the comments except the one that contains ["model.Store@4996fa8","model.Store@949eac1","model.Store@c45f266" ),